# Locate of the string in a multi-line textbox?

Tags: vb.net, string, textbox

For example, if we write:

```
Textbox1.Text = "Hello"
```

If the `textbox` is `MultiLine`, how can we control the location of the string in 2nd line of the `textbox`?

Comment: textbox1.Text = Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & "Hello"  ?

Answer (score 0):

What means *control*? Do you want to locate the indices or do you want to replace a line with this text?

If you want to determine the line(s) with the text "Hello":

```
Dim lineIndices = textbox1.Lines.
    Select(Function(line, index) New With { .Line = line, .Index = index }).
    Where(Function(x) x.Line.Contains("Hello")).
    Select(Function(x) x.Index)
```

If you want to replace a line of a textbox with a given text:

```
Dim index As Int32 = 1 ' second line '
If textbox1.Lines.Length > index Then
    textbox1.Lines(index) = "Hello"
Else
    Dim emptyLines = index - textbox1.Lines.Length
    textbox1.Lines = textbox1.Lines.
        Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("", emptyLines)).
        Concat({"Hello"}).ToArray()
End If
```